# Google Chromeでalert()やwindow.comfirm()などのメッセージをEscで閉じると、テキストフォームに文字入力ができなくなる

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chromeで `alert()` や `window.comfirm()` などのメッセージをEscで閉じると、テキストフォームに文字入力ができなくなります。

・Chromeのバージョン: 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64ビット)
・OS：Windows 10 Home

この事象を回避する方法、ご存じありませんか？
そしてChromeの不具合なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

明らかにバグですね。回避策があるかどうか存じませんが、とりあえず、下記ページの左上の☆をクリックすることで投票することができます。

[Issue 985694: Cannot use text input fields after closing alert message](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=985694)

Comment: https://crbug.com/1085949 も同様の問題のように見えます．（詳細は確認していませんが[未レビューの関連コミット](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2336054)があります）